# How to bind the single table template into all the 3 sections in knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a div which contains 3 sections.

```
<div>
    <section> /--bind table Table.html template with HR Details--/</section>
    <section> /--bind table Table.html template with Developers--/</section>
    <section> /--bind table Table.html template with Managers--/</section>
</div>
```

and i have a table template i.e Table.html

```
<table id="emptable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: EmpDetails">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25%" data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td style="width:25%" data-bind="text: Designation"></td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to use the same table in all the 3 sections with different observables.
For Eg: My Obserevables are HRDetails, Develeopers,Managers. 
I want to use same table structure in all the sections with different observables.
Please suggest me how to do this is in knockoutjs.

Answer (score 2):

How about something along the lines of

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.HRDetails = ko.observable(/* ... */);
    self.Develeopers = ko.observable(/* ... */);
    self.Managers = ko.observable(/* ... */);

    self.sections = [self.HRDetails, self.Develeopers, self.Managers];
}
```

and

```
<div data-bind="foreach: sections">
    <section data-bind="template: {name: 'yourTableTemplate'}">
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: should i specify the "foreach" attribute in the template data-bind ??

Comment: @ebramtharwat No, not necessarily. The `template` binding will work on the current `section` if you don't specify anything else.

Comment: so it 'll take the data inside each loop of section and use as it's data??

Comment: @ebramtharwat You don't need to specify `data` either. The `foreach` binding sets the context, the `template` uses the context. If  `HRDetails`, `Develeopers` and `Managers` have the same structure and the template can render that structure then you don't need to specify anything besides the template name.

Comment: @ebramtharwat If you prepare a jsFiddle with your current set-up then I could try to improve it.